# Section-specific (SALES-SERVICE-MARKETING) default dashboard in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dashboard, dynamics-crm-2013

Right now I am customizing a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 system.

I just created two (system) dashboards (one for SALES and one for SERVICE).

I know you can choose a "(general) default dashboard" that is shown when the user clicks on the "Home" button in the CRM / when the user visits the CRM page, but I was not able to find out if it is possible to assign a specific dashboard to each section (sales-services-marketing) (e.g. the user switches to the "Sales" section - my "SALES" dashboard should be shown / the user switches to the "Service" section - my "SERVICE" dashboard should be shown).

I'd be glad if somebody could tell if this is possible and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'DefaultDashboard' property in the sitemap for each sub-menu.  You can [set the value manually](http://www.hellokg.com/2013/12/15/changing-default-dashboards-in-the-sitemap-in-dynamics-crm-2013/) or use the [XrmToolBox](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.fi/2014/02/change-default-dashboard-in-dynamics.html).

Comment: Just tried the XrmToolBox and it works perfectly - thank you :)